# Devise current_user not working after making registration a partial via application helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, helper

So earlier, my devise code would work no problem. However, today, upon changing up some of the website, including making my devise registration a partial and adding the following code to my application helper (sorry this was wrong earlier, was tired :P)

```
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end
```

the current_user method no longer works. Could anyone tell me why?

The code for the partial is

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
 </div>

 <div class="panel-body"> 
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Name</font></h5>
      <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Company </font></h5>
      <%= f.text_field :company, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Real Estate Email </font></h5>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Telephone</font></h5>
      <%= f.telephone_field :telephone, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Password </font></h5>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <h5> <FONT FACE="HELVETICA NEUE"> Confirm Your Password </font></h5>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. What does your partial look like and what all things did you change exactly!

Comment: Agreed - more code is needed. Specifically, your `partial` & `application helper`

Answer (score 0):

The issue will likely be this:

> making my devise registration a partial

---

**current_user**

When you mention your `current_user` method "no longer works", I don't think the case will be it won't be working; it will likely be your changes which are *preventing* it from working.

Without code, I can only speculate, but there are several things you need to clear up:

--

`event handler`

You mention you have included the `Devise` `resource helpers` in your "`event_handler`". I'm not sure what you mean, but the surest way to get this working is to use the [official Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app) & put it in `application_helper.rb`:

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
```

--

`partial`

You mentioned you're using a `partial` to get show the `devise registration view`. This is fine, but how are you passing the data to it? You'll probably have an issue whereby you cannot access the `resource` helper, as it's been assigned to the `event_handler`

Comment: Sorry I mixed up my terminology. I meant application helper and not event handler.

Comment: lol okay that explains a lot! If you can't find any more solutions, comment here and we can go to chat if you want